# Set a page as default active in report without using page name

Tags: powerbi-embedded

How to set a page as an default active page in my embedded report?
I don't want to use the page name. Is there any other way so that whenever my report loads the page I specified is the default page?

Ex. I have `page 1`, `page 2` and `page 3` in my report, so by default `page 1` loads
. How could I set something so that by default `page 2` loads?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The report will open on the page, which was active when you saved the report in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that:

1. On Power BI [service](https://app.powerbi.com/), set the page as selected and save the report. When you embed the report, that page will be displayed as default active page.
2. Use [setActive()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/page-navigation#make-the-current-page-active) on load event

For 2nd way, please follow the below code snippets:

a. Get a reference to the HTML element that contains the embedded report:

```js
const embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];
```

b. Embed the `report`:

```js
const report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, embedConfig);
```

c. Retrieve the `page collection` of your report:

```js
const pages = await report.getPages();
```

d. Use page indexing to get the particular page and `setActive()` to set it as default active page. As per your example, you can try this:

```js
pages[2].setActive();
```

Please refer:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/embed-report#example
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/get-visuals#how-to-get-a-list-of-pages
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/page-navigation#make-the-current-page-active